# Captivate - html5 export adds a first slide with a play button

Tags: javascript, html, adobe-captivate

When I publish my captivate 6 project to html5, making sure autoplay is on, an extra first slide is being added which just contains a play button, as if you would publish to swf withtout autoplay enabled.

When I check the .js file, autoplay is enabled and everything looks fine.

I've read that you can't remove this play button when you publish to html5. Is this right? Because that would be quite stupid.

Or does someone knows some kind of .js hack to overrule this first slide?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I managed to overrule the button by changing the `<body>` tag in index.html to `<body onLoad="cp.movie.play()">`