# Adobe Captivate 8 - Remove playbar, enable autoplay for HTML output

Tags: adobe-captivate

I have a problem similar to:

[Captivate - html5 export adds a first slide with a play button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11930679/captivate-html5-export-adds-a-first-slide-with-a-play-button)

However, unlike that question, I cannot get the project to autoplay in the HTML output at all.

I'm trialling captivate to see if I can create an interactive set of activities, but I have two key criteria:

- no "playbar" visible at the start
- no "playbar" to get the activity flow going.

I've already worked out how to do both, by changing the skin properties to remove the play bar. However, without the playbar, there seems to be no way to start the presentation!!!

What am I missing here? Do I need to change the JS in the generated index.html to automatically start the presentation?

Answer (score 0):

There should be an AutoPlay option in the Preferences section that you can select to cause the module to start automatically, I am not running Captivate 8 but I know it works in Captivate 7.

Comment: The auto play is set by default and it still doesn't autoplay